# Exec dialog command from Expect Script

Tags: linux, bash, dialog, exec, expect

I tested the line below in TCLSH and it works:

```
dialog --title "Text" --msgbox "Text" 8 60
```

However, if I try it in a Expect script with "exec", it will just hang:

```
exec dialog --title "Text" --msgbox "Text" 8 60
```

I did a little research, it seems there is no need to escape special characters, but maybe that is the issue?

Do you guys have any suggestion to make this code work? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the interactive `tclsh` would behave like a *shell* (like `Bash`) and it'll handle unknown commands as external executables and auto *exec* them. That's why you can directly run `dialog` from within `tclsh`. This can be turned off by defining the *global* `auto_noexec` var. For example:

```
[bash] # tclsh
% echo hello world
hello world
% set auto_noexec "the value does not matter"
1
% echo hello world
invalid command name "echo"
%
```

For the `exec` command, by default it would not print the output to the terminal. You should use `>@ stdout` or/and `2>@ stderr`:

```
exec dialog --title Text --msgbox Text 8 60 >@ stdout 2>@ stderr
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimenting a bit, it will work as expected if you send stdout directly to the terminal

```
exec dialog --title "Text" --msgbox "Text" 8 60 >/dev/tty
```